# BS How to check existence of Span or not?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello guys i get this code in beautiful soup

```
<div class="user_info_right d-flex">
                <div class="info_one col" style="background-color: black">
                    <h2>INFO</h2>
                    <table class="table_transparen">
                        <tbody>



                            <tr>
                                <th>Country/State</th>
                                <td>Tennessee</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <td>Nashville</td>
                            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <td>Nashville , Tennessee</td>
                            </tr>                            <tr>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <td>                                     <a href="/region_9/country_19/city_1241">Smash</a>
                                                                  </td>
                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                <th>Hours</th>
```

I need to get **Nashville , Tennessee** but sometime the field " Address
Nashville , Tennessee doesn't exist !
So i can't just find data between City and  Category

So my question if how i can check if Address exist or not ?

Thank you so much

Comment: why did you tag scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to check if there is a th tag with Address as its text node, if this not the case find() will return None. ( the code below is self explanatory ;) )

```
address_th = soup.find("th",string="Address")
print(address_th)
if address_th is not None:
    address_value = address_th.find_next_sibling().text
    print(address_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to find `<th>` tag that contains the string "Address". If this tag exists, get next `<td>` tag:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<div class="user_info_right d-flex">
                <div class="info_one col" style="background-color: black">
                    <h2>INFO</h2>
                    <table class="table_transparen">
                        <tbody>



                            <tr>
                                <th>Country/State</th>
                                <td>Tennessee</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <td>Nashville</td>
                            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <td>Nashville , Tennessee</td>
                            </tr>                            <tr>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <td>                                     <a href="/region_9/country_19/city_1241">Smash</a>
                                                                  </td>
                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                <th>Hours</th>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

address = soup.select_one('th:-soup-contains(Address) + td')
if address:
    print(address.text)
```

Prints:

```
Nashville , Tennessee
```